# using regex in sqlite or mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I'm using sqlite3 to try and find users who have an e-mail address that is either with Gmail, Yahoo or Hotmail.  It needs to do this just on the basis of the first part of the domain, so  I want any address that had the @yahoo to be accepted.

It appears from documentation that it is not possible to use a regular expression when querying an sqlite database.  Is there any elegant way of doing something similar?  It doesn't seem to be possible to use a "like/in" with multiple options (eg: LIKE (%@yahoo%, %@gmail%, %@hotmail%)?

Failing that, I may switch over to MySQL for a reg exp as I want to keep the solution simple and elegant and DB isn't a major factor.  How would said regexp query be written in MySQL?

Answer (score 2):

You can't use multiple "LIKE" in that way but you can use:

```
(email LIKE "%@yahoo%" OR email LIKE "%@gmail%" OR ....)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want something like this (RLIKE function):

```
WHERE email RLIKE '^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.([A-Z]{2}|com|org|net|edu|gov|mil|biz|info|mobi|name|aero|asia|jobs|museum|travel)$'
```

If you use whatever_cs (case sensitive collation), use a-zA-Z instead of A-Z.

You can also get rid of ^ and $ in the regex. ^ means "starts with" and $ means "ends with"

UPDATE:

```
'.*@(gmail|hotmail|yahoo)\.[A-Z]{2,4}'
```

Comment: Have no idea, why I can not comment Michaels post, so I commenting myy own: regular expressions do not utilize indexes! But still my approach is better then "LIKE ''... OR.... LIKE ... OR .... LIKE .... OR...." etc...

Comment: Thanks for this.  How would this be edited to remove the requirement to look for a particular match of TLD at the end?  IE: If I just wanted it to accept any domain.

Comment: There are plenitudes of regular expression on email addresses. Personally I like '^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.(?:[A-Z]{2}|com|org|net|edu|gov|mil|biz|info|mobi|name|aero|asia|jobs|museum|travel)$' most. So, your RLIKE statement would look like I've edited above in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help here, but I'm actually not looking for it to do any checking except that after the @ there is a gmail, yahoo or hotmail.  Can you tell me how this regexp/rlike would look for mysql?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the way Nemoden is using or something like this (not tested)

```
WHERE email REGEXP '[\w\.]+@(yahoo|gmail|ymail|hotmail)\.(com|ru|co\.uk)'
```

This would be much faster because `LIKE %string% OR ...` is very slow and doesnt use any indexes(dont know if REGEXP uses indexes tho).